# Drupal Page View not being added to Main Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Drupal 7 Views has a "Menu" button that should allow one to add a Page View to the Main Menu. I have cloned a view, modified the "Path" and "Menu" parameter. It seems simple enough, because when I create a View via "Add View" I can add that view to the main menu. But, cloning a view and then modifying the "Menu" params does not cause a menu item to show up in the main menu. I have cleared cache a number of times but still nothing appears in the main menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be silly, but do you happen to save the view after cloning?

Also, make sure that the path is not already existing within you Drupal site.
A view creates a menu entry, check within you menu items listing that this entry is enabled.